# What's the origin of the word "mimo"?

Tags: etimología, significado, origen

I was wondering what's the origin/etymology for the word "mimo" ("mimar", "mimoso", etc.). Not in reference to a mime, but the 'cuddling' meaning.

I guess it has a social/regional origin, rather than an absorption from another language, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Está complicado. En la RAE la etimología figura como 'de origen expresivo' así que supongo que no está del todo claro de dónde surgió esa acepción para la palabra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding in website from RAE, the [*Mapa de diccionarios*](https://apps2.rae.es/ntllet/SrvltGUILoginNtlletPub) shows in the Dictionary of 1780 the next definition of *Mimar*

> . Hacer caricias, halagos y amores á otro. *Blandiri, mimos facere*.

The italic words are the latin translation of the word, so it's looks that the origin is Latin. But in other romance language (Italian or French) use other words. Only in the iberian romance languages survive the verb *mimar*.

Comment: Y por tanto, no podemos descartar la hipótesis de un origen árabe, de hecho en ese sitio en algunas entradas se sugiere también 'mima' como supuesto término del que provendría.

Comment: En italiano sí existe _mimmo_ con el significado de "pequeño" y especialmente "niño pequeño". Un [diccionario etimológico](http://www.etimo.it/?cmd=id&id=10983&md=d21f475370bc3862287d73d6205efcfd) lo asocia al latín _mínimus_ y a la palabra española para "caricia". Sin embargo, la referencia es mínima.